Обособление вводной конструкции при однородных членах
Моя бабушка вела предельно честный, по ее собственному выражению объективный дневник.
Может ли по ее собственному выражению выделяться запятыми с двух сторон?

Я вижу здесь еще одно пунктуационное решение для этого предложения.
Оно представляется мне более удобным, потому что вопрос "ставить или не ставить запятую после определения объективный?" отпадает.
Из ПАС: "уточняющие члены при подчеркивании смысла выделяются или отделяются тире..."
Тогда предложение будет иметь такой вид:
Моя бабушка вела предельно честный — по ее собственному выражению, объективный — дневник.
В этом случае вводное сочетание "по ее собственному выражению" от определения, конечно же, запятой отделяется.

Если обособить вводное слово, то могут возникнуть сомнения относительно отнесенности предложения к одному из однородных членов. Поэтому такое обособление нежелательно.

По правилам ПАС вводное сочетание можно присоединить ко второму однородному определению:

Моя бабушка вела предельно честный, по ее собственному выражению объективный дневник.
 § 94. Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на 
 границе однородных членов или частей сложного 
 предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними 
 слову или предложению, не отделяются от него 
 запятой (вторая запятая опускается с целью 
 указания на отнесенность вводного слова к 
 последующей части предложения)


По Розенталю возможен такой вариант:

Моя бабушка вела предельно честный, по ее собственному выражению объективный, дневник.
Розенталь, пункт 4, примечание:
При наличии однородных определений, когда может 
возникнуть сомнение, к какому из них относится 
находящееся между ними вводное слово, второе 
определение вместе с вводным словом **может 
образовать уточняющую конструкцию**: *Эти сведения 
почерпнуты из нового, **кажется специально для 
данного случая составленного**, отчёта* — без 
вводного слова между однородными определениями 
стояла бы запятая.


При другой семантике однородные члены можно поменять местами.


А такие варианты возможны?1. Моя бабушка вела предельно честный по ее собственному выражению, объективный дневник. 2. Моя бабушка вела предельно честный, по ее собственному выражению, объективный дневник.

ПАС § 94 разрешает присоединять к следующему однородному члену: Моя бабушка вела предельно честный, по ее собственному выражению объективный дневник.  Про предыдущий ничего не сказано,в то же время  можно предположить, что это тоже верно. //Розенталь рекомендует перейти к уточняющему обороту, и этот вариант смотрится  наилучшим образом. // Если вводное слово относится к первому однородному члену, то можно его поставить на второе место: Моя бабушка вела объективный, предельно честный по ее собственному выражению, дневник.

Присоединение вводного слова к уточняющему обороту  – это более частотный вариант, еще из правил 1956 года. А присоединение к однородным членам и предложениям  – это уже нововведение, не все его принимают.  В этом случае вводное сочетание ставится в позицию необособленного наречного выражения.

Можно еще так:
Моя бабушка вела предельно честный и объективный, по ее собственному выражению, дневник.
Это еще удобнее, так как подчеркивать ничего не будем, а вводное сочетание (источник информации) будет обособлено.
